# Can BitArray be dynamic? Or is List<bool> the only way?

Tags: c#, .net

Taking a look at BitArray's methods, I could not see any method to add a new boolean to the array - so is the size of BitArray static? I am using a lot (millions, maybe tens of millions) of bits so would really love the advantage of BitArray using only 1/8th of space of boolean array - however, I need it to be dynamic. Is the use of `List<bool>` my only way to use the dynamic length? Or perhaps `List<byte>` and bitwise operations on that - is there some way around that?

Comment: Even 100 million bits is just 12.5 megabytes. Why not just allocate the thing to the maximum expected size and forget about making it dynamic?

Comment: The problem is I do not have a maximum expected size - I am writing a compression algorithm  and the maximum size would depend on the file size ...

Comment: In that case, the maximum size could be larger than memory. You should have a fixed buffer and when it fills, flush it to disk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a wrapper class around it which implements `IList<bool>`, but uses a BitArray to store the data. Remember, you can resize a `BitArray` using the [Length property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I had never realized that the Length property had a setter... that's good to know.

Comment: If I just ++ed the Length every time, that would probably not be very wise in terms of performance?

Comment: @neuromouse: No, that would not perform well at all.

Comment: @neuromouse according to the code it doesn't simply just raise the length by one, from what I can tell. I'd just try it, is the extra few milliseconds really going to matter in your application?

Comment: Adding a wrapper would mean: Wrapper.Capacity == BitArray.Length and creating your own, new, Wrapper.Length property.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: It looks like it grows by a single element of the 32-bit integer array.  It won't shrink by fewer than 256 elements at once, though.  Therefore if you don't want to store an invalid length, you could round up to a multiple of 256*32 = 8192 bits, then assign length back to the real value.

Comment: I am concerned about how this enlargements are implemented - how the BitArray is really enlarged in the memory. Maybe I should just enlarge the size by a million at a time when needed?

Comment: @neuromouse: calling Setter to "Length" property costs O(n) operations. Everytime we resize the array, it's copied into a new-length array. Different from Getter, it costs only O(1) operation. [From MSDN]

Comment: It actually stores as an array of ints: 
    `int[] m_array;`
and indexing using shift operator: 
    `(m_array[index / 32] & (1 << (index % 32))) != 0;`

Comment: @kunthet: I am new to .net - can you tell me where on the MSDN have you found that info?

Comment: @neuromouse: Sorry, I didn't attach the link. You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).